# Emacs comment/uncomment current line

Tags: emacs, elisp

I know there's already an Emacs question on this, and that it was closed, but I find it quite relevant and important.

Basically, I want to comment/uncomment the current line. I was expecting this to be fairly easy with a macro, but I found that it really isn't.

If the current line is commented, uncomment. If it is uncommented, comment it. And I would also to comment out the whole line, not just from cursor position.

I tried a macro like this:

<kbd>C-a</kbd>

```
'comment-dwim
```

But this only work to comment a line, not to uncomment it, if it's already commented.

I'm not sure of how easy it is, but if there's some way, I'd really like it.

Also, the reason I love this idea so much is that when I used Geany, I just used <kbd>C-e</kbd> and it was perfect.

Comment: See the "see also" at the bottom of (http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CommentingCode). il-debug looks pretty handy.

Comment: Emacs 25 has [`comment-line`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Comment-Commands.html) bound to `C-x C-;`.

Comment: If you like Geany comment / uncomment, you should select some lines with shift and arrows then use `M-;` the combinations `C-x C-;` or `C-a C-;` does not work.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try this function, and bind to your favorite key:

```
(defun toggle-comment-on-line ()
  "comment or uncomment current line"
  (interactive)
  (comment-or-uncomment-region (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position)))
```

Comment: `comment-or-uncomment-region` is misleading. It is working only for line.

Comment: @Maven It is working on a region, and the region passed in is from the beginning of the line to the end...

Comment: Hm!! Maybe I tested it in hurry. I will check again. If I select a region partially on a line, will it include the whole line ?

Answer (score 99):

Trey's function works perfectly, but it isn't very flexible.

Try this instead:

```
(defun comment-or-uncomment-region-or-line ()
    "Comments or uncomments the region or the current line if there's no active region."
    (interactive)
    (let (beg end)
        (if (region-active-p)
            (setq beg (region-beginning) end (region-end))
            (setq beg (line-beginning-position) end (line-end-position)))
        (comment-or-uncomment-region beg end)))
```

It comments/uncomments the current line or the region if one is active.

---

If you prefer, you can modify the function to jump to the next line after (un)commenting the current line like this:

```
(defun comment-or-uncomment-region-or-line ()
    "Comments or uncomments the region or the current line if there's no active region."
    (interactive)
    (let (beg end)
        (if (region-active-p)
            (setq beg (region-beginning) end (region-end))
            (setq beg (line-beginning-position) end (line-end-position)))
        (comment-or-uncomment-region beg end)
        (next-line)))
```

Note that only thing that's changed is the added `next-line` command at the end of the function.

Comment: This could actually be better if after commenting a line, the cursor moved to the next line, so repeatedly hitting a key binding would comment consecutive lines. Any tips for doing this?

Comment: @justingordon I edited an alternative version under the original. Enjoy!

Comment: This is great! It should be the default behavior.

Comment: It might make more sense to use `next-logical-line` rather than `next-line` so that in case the line is long, the user won't comment it then uncomment it again afterwards.

Comment: Thanks! I thought `C-;` was a nice chord for it, since I've just discovered the `M-;` shortcut too.

Comment: Would be nice if this was included in a package or standalone package

Comment: This one works also with evil mode, thanks!

Comment: Awesome function, thank you!
Is it possible to make it work on empty lines? It has a weird behavior on such lines.

Comment: This results in the selected region being de-selected. How can I keep the region selected after un/commenting?

Answer (score 14):

I took Trey's answer and refined it, so that it also works when a region is active, but then works on that region:

```
(defun comment-or-uncomment-line-or-region ()
  "Comments or uncomments the current line or region."
  (interactive)
  (if (region-active-p)
      (comment-or-uncomment-region (region-beginning) (region-end))
    (comment-or-uncomment-region (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position))
    )
  )

(define-key c-mode-base-map (kbd "C-/") 'comment-or-uncomment-line-or-region)
```

Comment: Thanks for also mentioning how to bind to a key combo.

Comment: I had to change the key combination part to this: `(global-set-key (kbd "<C-kp-divide>") 'comment-or-uncomment-line-or-region)` to make it work.

Comment: When I replace "C-/" by "C-m" it doe snot work. Why?

Comment: `C-m` is hardwired to `RET`, similar to how `C-g` is hardwired. I think you cannot use it for anything else.

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised the `comment-region` routine hasn't been mentioned. (Though I concede it may indicate I've missed something.) I've had the following line in my .emacs file for the better part of 20 years.  It works well in most major programming modes I care about.

`(global-set-key "\C-c\C-c" 'comment-region)`

From the docs of 'comment-region'

> Documentation: Comment or uncomment each line in the region. With just
>   C-u prefix arg, uncomment each line in region. Numeric prefix arg ARG
>   means use ARG comment characters. If ARG is negative, delete that many
>   comment characters instead. Comments are terminated on each line, even
>   for syntax in which newline does not end the comment.  Blank lines do
>   not get comments.

Comment: I +1'ed your answer because *comment-region* is always nice...  However as far as I can see it's not anywhere near as convenient as what OP is asking: he wants, no matter where he's on at the current line, to be able to toggle the comments on/off.  With *comment-region* one still has to: go at the beginning of the line, set the mark, go at the end of the line, and then comment-region (that's quite more work than a unique shortcut toggling comments on/off).  But then my Emacs-fu is not strong so I may be wrong on that...

Comment: The OP is aware of `comment-dwim` which is the super-set of `comment-region` functionality.

Comment: @TacticalCoder  Yeah, you're right.  I've been using comment-region tied to a toggle for so long that I glossed right over the appropriate details without seeing it.

Comment: @event_jr: No, `comment-dwim` is definitely [**not**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21066197/729907) a superset of `comment-region` functionality. This is a common misconception.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand how keyboard-macros work.  What @Trey provided is a Emacs-Lisp command.  You could have accomplished this for yourself without understanding Emacs-Lisp.

First figure out the sequence of keys that does what you want and then record that sequence as a macro.

You proposed this: <kbd>C-a M-;</kbd>  (M-; is `comment-dwim`).  Does it do what you had in mind?  If not then it's not going to magically work when you play it back as a keyboard macro.

Answer (score 1):

[**This answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20051788/729907) applies here.  It defines  command `comment-region-lines` that comments or uncomments the current line, or the region if active.

It is similar to `comment-or-uncomment-region`, but it **lets you decide** whether to uncomment or comment. It lets you *nest* comments, instead of automatically uncommenting the region if it is already commented out.

With a numeric prefix arg it uses that many comment-start chars (e.g., `;`, `;;`, `;;;`,... in Lisp). With a plain `C-u` prefix arg it uncomments. I bind it to `C-x C-;`.