# Toggle comment on line if region is not active

Tags: emacs

I use this as reference:
[Emacs comment/uncomment current line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688748/emacs-comment-uncomment-current-line/13095935#13095935)

My question is whether I can perform the same task using defadvice (which seems more appropriate to me)?
Something along the lines of

```lisp
(defadvice comment-or-uncomment-region (before mark-whole-line (arg beg end) activate)
  (unless (region-active-p)
    (setq beg (line-beginning-position) end (line-end-position))))
(ad-activate 'comment-or-uncomment-region)
```

Comment: `defadvice` is not more appropriate.  It's a last resort solution.  Keep in mind that whenever you use defadvice you are fundamentally modifying the Emacs API which package developers rely on.

Comment: I second event_jr's judgment. Why should a function that is explicitly named "comment-or-uncomment-region" work on the current line? I would argue that this is quite unpredictable behavior. The better way to go is probably to write a small utility function that does what your code sample indicates and bind that to `M-;` or the keyboard shortcut of your choice.

Comment: I (accidently?) thought it means moneky-patching to modify already-existing functions locally to my personal needs, instead of redefining them. This is just an example of many functions I expect to act on a whole line if no region is active - yank, kill and comment are just some examples.

Comment: @EladR It's easy to end up with that impression with the ridicilous amounts of wrong use of defadvice on the Emacs wiki.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is based on my comments above.

`defadvice` is not more appropriate than another solution.  It is never more
appropriate than another solution.

---

`defadvice` is a last resort for **when you can't fix your problem any other
way**.

**PERIOD.**

---

Keeping in mind that whenever you use `defadvice` you are fundamentally modifying
the Emacs API which package developers rely upon.

When you subtly changing these behaviours, you cause lots of problems for you
and eventually for the package developers when you report "bugs" because
your Emacs API was broken with `defadvice`.

So when you want to change functionality locally, the
way to do it is to define a new command using existing functionality and remap
to it.

To wit (from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9697222/903943) you referred to):

```
(defun comment-or-uncomment-region-or-line ()
    "Comments or uncomments the region or the current line if there's no active region."
    (interactive)
    (let (beg end)
        (if (region-active-p)
            (setq beg (region-beginning) end (region-end))
            (setq beg (line-beginning-position) end (line-end-position)))
        (comment-or-uncomment-region beg end)
        (next-line)))

(global-set-key [remap comment-dwim] 'comment-or-uncomment-region-or-line)
```