# Emacs keybinding to comment selection/multiple lines for SQL file?

Tags: sql, emacs, key-bindings

I have a .sql file that I am editing in Emacs 24, and I am looking for a way to comment out a selection or a line. Basically, I want a keybinding to add `--` at the line start (for single line comments) or `/*` and `*/` around the selected region (for variable line comments).

Perhaps there is something that I can add to my .emacs to enable such a keybinding? (I am a bit of a novice to Emacs) Thanks.

**EDIT**

After a little exploring, I found `M-x comment-region` to do the trick for single line comments. This was also very helpful:
[Comment Guide in Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Comment-Commands.html)

Still, how can I do variable line comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW, I use `comment-dwim` *only* for end-of-line comments (e.g., `;` at the end of a Lisp line).  I use it there to create the comment and also to reindent it.

I do ***not*** use `comment-dwim` to comment or uncomment a block of text, even though it does let you do that to some extent (it is limited in this regard, especially regarding nesting and the number of comment chars to use).

I prefer **`comment-region`** for that.  I bind `comment-region` to `C-x C-;`.  It lets me control or change the number of `;` chars to use for commenting (in Lisp mode).  And it lets me easily uncomment a block of text.  And it lets me comment a block of text that already contains commented blocks of text (nesting).  And it lets me uncomment a block of text a given level (unnesting a given level).

I cannot speak particularly about SQL mode commenting, but try `comment-region` and see if it doesn't do what you want.  Be sure to learn the use of different prefix arg possibilities.

FWIW, I don't know what you mean by "*variable line comments*".  If you mean (un)commenting a block of text, then see above.  If you mean something different, then please elaborate.

Note that in SQL code --- just as in Lisp code --- you can use the single-line comment syntax (`--` for SQL; `;` for Lisp) to comment out a *block* of text.  You need not use `/*...*/` in SQL for that.  I do that in my SQL code, for instance.

Comment: For my definition of *"variable line comments"*, I was trying to distinguish between intra-line comments and comments to a whole line. I am used to Eclipse in Java, where `C-/` comments out a whole region (prefixing each line with `//` in Java), even if cursor position is in the middle of the line, whereas `C-S C-/` will comment out only the SELECTED text, using the `/*...*/` style comments (ie *"variable line comments"* or *"intra-line"* comments). I was looking for similar behavior, but I suppose Emacs is a different beast altogether.

Answer (score 2):

The command `comment-dwim` can be used to comment or uncomment multiple lines in most major modes, including `sql-mode`. Just make sure to select a region before using it. It is bound to `M-;` by default.

Out of the box, this command uses `--` for both single and multiple line comments in `sql-mode`.

From `C-h f comment-dwim`:

> Call the comment command you want (Do What I Mean).
>
> If the region is active and `transient-mark-mode` is on, call `comment-region` (unless it only consists of comments, in which case it calls `uncomment-region`). Else, if the current line is empty, call `comment-insert-comment-function` if it is defined, otherwise insert a comment and indent it. Else if a prefix ARG is specified, call `comment-kill`. Else, call `comment-indent`. You can configure `comment-style` to change the way regions are commented.