# How to comment/uncomment line or region without marking completely the area I want to comment

Tags: emacs, elisp

Possible duplicate [Emacs comment/uncomment current line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688748/emacs-comment-uncomment-current-line)

I'd like something similar to Gerstmann's answer in the above question but the answer doesn't do too well if the end of the region isn't the end of the line. For example commenting using Gerstmann's function

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-;") 'backward-delete-char-untabify)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-c") 'comment-or-uncomment-region-or-line)
```

with region

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-;") '(STARTPOINT)backward-delete-char-untabify)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-c") 'comment-or-uncomment-(ENDPOINT)region-or-line)
```

will result in

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-;") ';; backward-delete-char-untabify)
;; (global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-c") 'comment-or-uncomment-
        region-or-line)
```

I'd like it to be this instead

```
;; (global-set-key (kbd "C-;") 'backward-delete-char-untabify)
;; (global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-c") 'comment-or-uncomment-region-or-line)
```

How can I do this and similarly with uncommenting, the same thing where uncommenting everything on the lines the region touches. I'm sure there are cases this might not be the idea commenting method but at the moment this seems better to me.

Answer (score 0):

You chose a poor example, since unlike some languages, LISP isn't line based.  So with your approach, starting from

```
(progn
  ~(foo)
  (bar)|)
```

you get:

```
(progn
  ;; (foo)
  ;; (bar))
```

which is an error.

Here's the code anyway, maybe you can use it for Python or something:

```
(defun comment-line-based (beg end)
  (interactive "r")
  (let (deactivate-mark)
    (goto-char beg)
    (beginning-of-line)
    (set-mark (point))
    (goto-char end)
    (end-of-line)
    (comment-dwim nil))
  (deactivate-mark))
```

It should work for both commenting and un-commenting.

Comment: Tried this in a go file with go-mode, company, and helm mode on but the behavior is strange, even calling the comment-line-based on a single line anywhere will always comment more than 1 line. As for the reason I'd want this, I like this lazy method of commenting as I haven't run into a situation where the original method was more useful (I currently do not code in any lisp language)